# python string format keyError

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm getting the following error while trying to execute my script

```
 ]""".format(id="123", name="test")
KeyError: '\n    "id"'
```

Here's my script. I just need to format a multiline string. I tried using a dictionary in the format section but that didn't work either.

```
import requests

payload = """[
  {
    "id":{id},
    "name": "{name}"
  }
]""".format(id="123", name="test")

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/employee", data=payload, 
headers=headers)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Comment: Use the `json` module to avoid problems. In fact, `requests` can do that for you. Don't try and format a json string yourself.

Comment: For the issue itself: escape the braces that aren't part of the formatting: `"""[\n  {{\n    "id"`...`\n  }}\n]"""`.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: It's in the stdlib documentation for the json module, the requests documentation for how requests can take care of it by itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You have opening and closing brackets. Format interprets them as a placeholder, you as a dict. Its content is, as the error says, `\n    "id":{id}…` and so on. If you do not mean `{` as a placeholder, double them.
2. You are trying to write json yourself. Don't to that. Use the `json` module:

   ```
   json.dumps({"id": "123", name: "test"})
   ```

   Or even better: Let requests do that.

Answer (score 8):

When using `format`, literal `{`'s and `}`'s need to be [escaped by doubling them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
payload = """[
  {{
    "id":{id},
    "name": "{name}"
  }}
]

""".format(id="123", name="test")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using %s instead of .format()

This works:

```
import requests

payload = """[
  {'id':%s,'name': %s
}
]"""%("123","test")

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/employee", data=payload,
headers=headers)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Comment: That's usable as a work-around, but doesn't solve the actual underlying issue.

Comment: @Evert: OP wrote in the question "I just need to format a multiline string" and I provided a way. I don't think the solution is incorrect and thus doesn't deserve the downvote!

Comment: @Evert: Sorry, I don't understand which values I didn't quote. I pasted the code after I was successfully able to run the code on my machine. (Obviously 8080 returned "Connection refused" but there is no syntax error.

Comment: Got it! nice catch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166715/discussion-between-vimanyu-and-evert).